# Changing variable value from different scope

Tags: c#, winforms

If I have Form1 & Form2, and I have the event `button1_Click` in Form1, such that:

```
System.Void button1_Click(System.Object  sender, System.EventArgs  e) {
static boolean x= false;
..
..
Form2.Show();
}
```

I want when closing Form2, to put x=true, how to do that

Comment: Looks like C++ to me. But looking at the word 'boolean', I start to doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Form2 otherForm = new Form2();
bool x = false;
otherForm.FormClosing += (s,args)=> x = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `x` to be a public static `property` or `field`. `x` should be declared at class level to make it visible to other classes.

Then, simply update the static property from From2 as you need.

Comment: eww...no.  There is no need to change it's visibility at all, and it's preferable not to.  Don't expose state at a higher scope than you have to.